# Network Issues: Ubuntu Server 16.04 on a Macmini 1,1 (Late 2006)

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, mac, 32-bit

I'm having issues getting my old Mac Mini to connect to the internet or LAN in any way. Even pinging the router gives me Destination Host Unreachable. I'm using a 32 bit 16.04.5 Ubuntu Server iso (i386) after having trouble getting the amd64+mac 14.04 version to work.

The install went fairly smooth up until the network configuration, where the installer struggled to configure the network properly. I had to configure the network with a static IP instead of using the default DHCP. Once that was done, the install finished with no obvious errors. It never explicitly said it finished installing a file, but the number of files remaining would still shrink.

Once the install finished, I was unable to install any packages or otherwise connect to the network. /etc/network/interfaces appeared to have the right gateway, subnet mask, IP and the like. I worry that the firmware to properly use this ethernet card might be malfunctioning.

output of lshw -class network:

```
*—network 
    description: Ethernet interface 
    product: 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 
    physical id: 0
    bus info:  pci@0000:01:00.0
    logical name: enp1s0 
    version: 22
    serial: 00:16:cb:a9:47:9f
    size: 10Mbit/s 
    capacity: 1Gbit/s 
    width: 64 bits 
    clock: 33MHz 
    capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=half ip=192.168.66.214 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
    resources: irq:26 memory:90200000-90203fff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90200000-90203fff
*-network DISABLED 
    description: Wireless interface 
    product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    logical name: wls1
    version: 01 
    serial: 00:17:f2:53:3d:1e
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver:ath5k driverversion=4.4.0-131-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
    resources: irq:17 memory:90100000-9010ffff
```

output of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface 
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 

# The primary network interface 
auto enp1s0
#iface enp1s0 inet dhcp
iface enp1s0 inet static 
    address 192.168.66.214
    netmask 255.255.255.0 
    network 192.168.66.0 
    broadcast 192.168.66.255 
    gateway 192.168.66.252 
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package
    dns-nameservers 192.168.66.252 
    # dns-search clusternet.com -- this was required in the install, not 
    # otherwise used
```

Any idea what I should try? I'm a newcomer to Ubuntu so I could easily have missed something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Well, doing a reinstall and retrying the automatic configuration over and over again eventually got it to work. If someone was able to tell me what I did wrong I would appreciate it, but the automatic configuration was able to fix it in the end.